# What happens If the interrupt occurs during the execution of HALT instruction?

Tags: computer-architecture, addressing, stack, stack-pointer

Consider the following program segment on a hypothetical processor .
[image]

---

I have this question in my course CS201.
Suppose this processor has 32 bits Load/Store operations, ALU operations is 16 bits and Branch instruction is 16 bits. Program has been loaded in the memory with a starting address of 3000 (which is in decimal) .

Assuming Byte addressing, If the interrupt occurred during the execution of halt instruction, then the return address pushed onto the stack will be ?

---

**My Try :**

I referred this link

http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_134.html

According to this link, The return address saved on the stack must be of instruction after the HALT instruction, which gives me the saved address as

3000 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 2 = 3018

Hence, Stack saves 3018 .

---

But, I don't have the answer with me, so I can't confirm it.

Am I going Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The return address saved on the stack must be of instruction after the HALT instruction

Of course. Otherwise the CPU would go into a HALT instruction again after returning from the interrupt.

> Suppose this processor has 32 bits Load/Store operations, ALU operations is 16 bits and Branch instruction is 16 bits.

Some information is missing: Either the information, that "HALT" is a "branch" instruction on the given CPU (on modern automotive CPUs "HALT" is a special instruction class, not "branch") or the information how long "HALT" is.

> 3000 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 2 = 3018

Assuming "HALT" is also 16 bits long: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: If interrupts are disabled by software, nothing will happen within HALT instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! Just one doubt "Interrupt comes during the halt instruction" and "Interrupt comes after halt instruction", both are same ? I think so, because interrupts are always processed after completion of instruction. Am I right here ?

Comment: Yes, @Garrick, you are right. An interrupt is processed only after current instrucion has completed

Comment: Depending on the implementation, HALT may not be so benign... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire#Intel_x86